# Fade in/out an element in a div with mouse over/out of div

Tags: jquery, gallery, mouseover, fade, mouseout

sorry for the stupid title, I couldn't think of anything else, and I'm sorry if someone already asked this, I couldn't find it.

Anyway, I'm making a gallery with jQuery. I have a div and a picture and previous/next buttons inside that div. The buttons are positioned over the picture and I want them to be hidden by default, to fade in when I move mouse over the div, and fade out when I move mouse out of the div. The problem is when I move mouse from the picture to a button, javascript registers that as the mouseout event, even though I didn't actually leave the div which holds the picture and buttons. I made a quick fiddle to show you what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ppbm/

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `hover` function:

```
$("#button").hide();

$("#container").hover(function(){
    $("#button").fadeIn();
},function(){
    $("#button").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is a timeout that'll stall it from simply fading out again and again.
Also on a side note, use the `.on()` which is new to jQuery 1.7.2

```
$("#button").fadeOut();
var timer;

$("#container img").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#button").fadeIn();
    },
    mouseout : function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () { 
            $("#button").fadeOut();
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ppbm/4/)

Comment: Updated it, just seeing that now

Comment: That is a workaround, but too complicated, thanks for your effort anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it with CSS transitions? They are supported everywhere except IE < 10.
http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Your example modified:
http://jsfiddle.net/b4e4M/

Comment: Because I asked how to do it with JavaScript.